# renderEnd not firing on Horizontal Bar Chart [nvd3]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Let me preface with saying I have bar, pie and line charts where renderEnd all works fine.

I'm trying to modify the styling on a horizontal bar chart, which I can do fine either in the callback or renderEnd and the results can be seen in the browser. The problem occurs when resizing the window, all the custom styling is removed and the chart resets.

Testing render end with a simple console.log on all my other charts, the log fires each time the window is resized, as far as I understand renderEnd should, but on my horizontal bar chart this simply isn't the case and it only gets fired when the page loads.

Here's two plunker's of a horizontal bar chart and a vertical bar chart, if you open the console and watch the height (on horizontal) and width (on vertical) you can see that renderEnd only fires on load on the horizontal chart but fires on load and each time the window is resized on the vertical chart.

If anybody could help me out with this I'd greatly appreciate it!

Horizontal Bar Chart:
http://embed.plnkr.co/ua2IGvShEt2zZeyRTZA2/

Vertical Bar Chart:
http://embed.plnkr.co/eMS2abmdegS8hArklKdY/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix your issue?

Comment: Nope. I no longer work with nvd3 either.